# what is the traditional zen stance on agriculture and animal care?

Tags: zen

its a pretty straight forward question. facts only please, no opinions, and i request that only an experienced and well practiced zen buddhist answer this question (to avoid speculation).

thanks.

Comment: I don't think we can honour requirements for certain types of people answering certain questions; this is a democratic forum and any member with a good answer is welcomed to answer any question. If you require that your answers be from a specific subset of humans that is different from the subset making up the entirety of this forum, then I think you should look elsewhere for your answers. If anyone disagrees with me, maybe we should take it up in [meta](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think it's fair to to ask answers come from a particular school of thought. Otherwise, that's exactly how SE works.

Comment: This is a vegetarianism question right? Chinese Chan is vegetarian (as is Korean, Vietnamese and Japan up to the Meiji Reformation). Animals are not to be eaten, people who take Upsasaka Vows don't own animals. Bodhisattva Vows, required to rescue animals, including farm animals. But US and Japanese Zen are generally not vegetarian, but vegetarians are over represented by about a factor of 50. This question is probably a dupe if it is a vegetarian question, unless the other Q has some sort of deficit.

Comment: @MatthewMartin It might have been a question related to whether it should have been acceptable for the OP to bring his dog to a multi-day meditation camping retreat.

Comment: Oh that one again.

Comment: @MatthewMartin 1) I believe bhante was commenting on "i request that only an experienced and well practiced zen buddhist answer this question" versus "I'm looking for zen answers". 2) it does not look like a vegetarianism question to me.... and why "agriculture"? "the traditional stance" WTH? -- hence my answer :)

Comment: There is something interesting to say about Chan, Buddhism & farming. The old vinaya prohibits farming (or any work for pay & profit really). But in ancient China, begging was illegal & gov't support was iffy. So Chan monasteries started farming. They raised vegetables (although one book I read says it was mostly share croppers peasants that raised the rice) & kept donated animals but didn't eat them. What this guy wanted for an answer (maybe he lives on a farm), dunno, but farm animals get mention in both the Bodhisattva precepts & Upaseka precepts.

Answer (score 1):

> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >                   Cut the bull!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a well practiced zen buddhist but just a practitioner of zen buddhism. I do not know the answer but I do know where I would look for this answer. If I were tasked with finding the above I would look in the Diamond Sutra.

> "The Diamond Sutra advises us to throw away is the notion “man,” human being. This is not too difficult. When we look into the human being, we see human ancestors, we see animal ancestors, we see vegetable ancestors, we see mineral ancestors. We see that the human is made of non-human elements. We see that we are at the same time a rock, a river, a cloud, a squirrel, a rose. And if we take away all the non-human elements, the human being is no longer there.
>
> This is the deepest teaching on deep ecology. In order to protect the human being, you have to protect elements that are not human, because these elements are our ancestors, and if you destroy them there is no way we can be here. That is why discrimination between man and nature is a wrong view. You have to see you as nature, one with nature.
>
> That is why harmony, respect of life, is possible. So throw away the idea that the human being is the boss, man is the boss, man can do anything to nature. The key is contemplation on impermanence of non-self."
>
> -Thich Nhat Hanh, Dharma Talk: Free from Notions, Ocean of Peace Meditation Hall
> Deer Park Monastery
> Sunday, September 25, 2001